# Why I get this error using TSQL to find a connected graph?

Tags: t-sql, breadth-first-search

nodes(nodeID int) is a list of all nodes.
edges(fromNodeID int, toNodeID int) is the relationship between two nodes.
Assume the graph is undirected, find all the connected components.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getGraph
    AS BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE graphs (node int, id int);
        DECLARE @graphID int;
        SET @graphID = 0;
    
        WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM graphs) < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM nodes))
        BEGIN
            CREATE TABLE currentGraph (node int);
            CREATE TABLE temp(node int);
            DECLARE @start int;
            SET @start = (SELECT TOP (1) n.paperID
                          FROM nodes n
                          WHERE n.paperID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM graphs));
            INSERT INTO currentGraph VALUES (@start);
            INSERT INTO temp (node) VALUES (
                SELECT e.citedPaperID
                FROM currentGraph cg, edges e
                WHERE cg.node = e.paperID
                );
    
            /* If there is any new node, keep searching for current graph*/
            WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM temp
                    WHERE temp.node NOT IN (SELECT * FROM currentGraph)) <> 0)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO currentGraph (node) VALUES (
                    SELECT t.node
                    FROM temp t
                    WHERE t.node NOT IN (SELECT * FROM currentGraph)
                    );
                DELETE FROM temp;
    
                INSERT INTO temp (node) VALUES (
                SELECT e.citedPaperID
                FROM currentGraph cg, edges e
                WHERE cg.node = e.paperID
                );
            END
            SET @graphID = @graphID + 1;
            INSERT INTO graphs (node, id) VALUES ((SELECT DISTINCT cg.node FROM currentGraph cg), @graphID);
        END
    END
```

Error message:

```
[2021-10-02 21:52:07] [S1000][156] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. [2021-10-02 21:52:07] [42000][102] Incorrect syntax near ')'.
[2021-10-02 21:52:07] [S1000][156] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. [2021-10-02 21:52:07] [42000][102] Incorrect syntax near ')'.
[2021-10-02 21:52:07] [S1000][156] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. [2021-10-02 21:52:07] [42000][102] Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Comment: [2021-10-02 21:52:07] [S1000][156] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
[2021-10-02 21:52:07] [42000][102] Incorrect syntax near ')'.
[2021-10-02 21:52:07] [S1000][156] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
[2021-10-02 21:52:07] [42000][102] Incorrect syntax near ')'.
[2021-10-02 21:52:07] [S1000][156] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
[2021-10-02 21:52:07] [42000][102] Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the error message to it.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is caused by the incorrect syntax of the INSERT statement.

You can use one of the following:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (SomeColumn) VALUES (constant);
INSERT INTO YourTable (SomeColumn, OtherColumn) SELECT FirstColumn, SecondColumn FROM AnotherTable;
INSERT INTO YourTable (SomeColumn) VALUES ((SELECT SingleColumn FROM AnotherTable));
```

(I did not look at the correctness of the rest of the code, so I cannot confirm if it solves your problem after fixing the syntax error)